# Find rooted sub-tree containing predefined set of values

Tags: algorithm, tree, breadth-first-search, backtracking, subtree

Given a tree of nodes find a rooted sub-tree that contains a set of predefined values. The nodes in the tree are unique but their associated values may be repeated.

Ideally the most shallow sub-tree is returned. The sub-tree may also be returned simply as an array of nodes (or their unique IDs).

Here are several atomic test cases with the ideal resulting sub-tree:

#1 `[A, A, B, C]`

```
        A1           Answer:      A1
      / | \                      /  \
    B1  D1 C1                   B1   C1
   /  \      \                 /
  A2   B2     B3              A2
```

#2 `[A, B, B, A]`

```
      A1              Answer(s):        A1            A1         A1         the first solution is preferred
     /  \                              / \           /            \         as it is most shallow
    B1   B2                           B1  B2        B1             B2
   /  \    \                         /             / \              \
  A2   B3   B4                      A2           A2   B3             B4
              \                                                       \
               A3                                                      A3
```

#3 `[A, A, B, C]`

```
      A1               Answer: Not possible as only one B can be matched
     /  \
    B1   B2
   /       \
  A2        C1
```

#4 `[B, B]`

```
     A1               Answer: Not possible as the root 'A' is not in the set
    /  \
   B1   B2
```

My approach was broken into two steps:

1. Breadth-first scan until all nodes in the set are found returning a tree that definitely contains the desired sub-tree.
2. Use backtracking to search the resulting sub-tree (essentially all permutations of the sub-tree) to find the exact nodes that satisfy the set.

However, this solution is not very efficient. It seems like I *should* be able to find the desired sub-tree simply by using a modified breadth-first search. I've also been unable to make this work in practice.

Comment: RE: "*However, this solution is not as efficient as I would like*", well, how efficient was it and how efficient would you like it to be?  Your description of your approach is not nearly detailed enough to figure out how efficient your implementation was.